How can I write a happy birthday message in Ruby to put on a cake?
Original Question
My boyfriend is celebrating his birthday shortly and I am ordering a custom cake for him. I want to write Happy Birthday on it in a clever Ruby coding way. It will be on a black background to make it the most realistic, and can choose various colors for the font. Here is what I have so far. Anything I should change to make it better/more accurate/nerdier?
So far I have the following:
#!/usr/sja/ruby*
@my_best_friend = “Larry”

puts “Happy 30th Birthday #{@my_best_friend}!”

Update
Based on some answers and comments, I've changed the code to:
EVENT = "30th birthday"
MY_BEST_FRIEND = "Larry"
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = "Sarah"
puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!", "Love, #{YOUR_BEST_FRIEND}"

Is there anything else I should do to make this work correctly or improve it?

Learning so much here. Thank you for all your input! I have a few versions that I will be running by the cake decorator to see what will fit. Also downloaded a Ruby app to run it to make sure it actually worked, and after a few tweaks (and a lot of googling) it does! Again, appreciate all the time you put in here to help me!

Since your cake probably doesn't come with a Ruby interpreter that could actually run the code – instead of writing code that would print something, you could also write (syntactically valid) Ruby code which resembles the message when read aloud. Something like happy 30.th(:birthday) do ... (you get the idea)

Regarding the use of images: it's perfectly fine to upload images when the problem specifically relates to how the code is rendered. The latter is an important part of your question because it also involves syntax highlighting (colors) and non-code element like line numbers. That being said, I'd love to see an image of the final cake! :)

I second @Stefan's comment an updated post with a picture of the cake is mandatory. post.downvote! unless post.update(content).include?(:cake_pic)

I will definitely add a photo of the final product! His birthday is the 6th of Sept so stay tuned.

A Few More Idiomatic and Flexible Versions
I applaud your intent, although this question is likely to be closed as somewhat off-topic because it's a "polling question" whether many opinions can be correct. However, if you're looking for something simple and idiomatic, you can vastly simplify what you've got since it isn't code that actually has to run (e.g. your shebang line doesn't actually need to point to a real Ruby interpreter) and some of the code works but can be compacted or made a bit more fun.
More Code and Variables
If you want a lot of variables, I'd recommend something like the following, replacing programmersgirlfriend with your actual name. The comments (except for the one on the first line, i.e. the shebang) are just for your information; remove them for the sake of compactness and less use of frosting!
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# Using constants seems appropriate here.
EVENT = "30th birthday"
MY_BEST_FRIEND = "Larry"
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = "programmersgirlfriend"
EM_DASH = "\u2014"

msg = "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!"
# Lead with an em-dash, and right-justify the "from"
# line based on the length of the message above.
sender = "\u2014 #{YOUR_BEST_FRIEND}".rjust(msg.length)
printf "%<to>s\n%<from>s", {to: msg, from: sender}

Advanced Inline Interpolation
If you just want compact but programmatic, and something that shows off some of Ruby's less common String interpolations, you can use something like the this example.
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Happy %s, %s!\n" % ["30th birthday", "Larry"]
puts "   -- %s\n" % "programmersgirlfriend"

Idiomatic Ruby That's Readable with More Flexible Design
Finally, you might consider using an indented here-document like the following because it gives you a lot of flexibility to actually see the layout rather than interpolating variables. That in turn allows you to line things up the way you want them to appear on the cake, although writing on a cake probably won't exactly match the fixed-width characters from the Ruby console.
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts <<~MSG_ON_CAKE
  Happy 30th birthday to
  my best friend, Larry!

  Your best friend,
  ProgrammersGirlfriend
MSG_ON_CAKE

This option is a good choice because it's very idiomatic Ruby. It uses a here-document (the code wrapped in the <<~ operator and bounded by the MSG_ON_CAKE delimiter) to define your String rather than interpolating constants or a lot of short-lived variables. It creates a String on the fly that is then passed to Kernel#puts. I personally like this option best, but it's your gift, Larry's birthday, and entirely a matter of taste!
Use a Closure for Extra Geek Points
This is totally unnecessary code for what you want to do, but if you're just having fun with it or think Larry would enjoy it, you might want to consider something like this that uses parallel assignment, a lambda closure (a type of Proc object with the uniquely compact syntax of ->{} in this case since it needs no arguments) with an inline Proc#call method that returns a Array of String objects to Kernel#puts for multi-line output.
#!/usr/bin/ruby

event, to_my_best_friend, your_best_friend =
  "30th birthday", "Larry", "ProgrammersGirlfriend"
puts ->{ ["Happy #{event} #{to_my_best_friend}!",
   "From #{your_best_friend}"] }.call

This assigns all the variables in a single line, although I broke it over two because it would otherwise be too long unless you're using a sheet cake. The same was done for the puts line. If you're using a sheet cake, you can make both lines single lines if you prefer.
The code creates an Array of String objects, interpolating from the variables in scope when the lambda is defined. It then calls itself, returning values for Kernel#puts to print to standard output. Despite the needless complexity, the actual printed output is still straightforward enough, and can be adjusted to suit.

Happy 30th birthday Larry!
From ProgrammersGirlfriend

Procs and lambdas are closures, which are not common constructs for a use case like this one. Maybe that will make it more fun! In any case, it's another option to consider, and like the others is perfectly valid Ruby code.
Using Your Own Updated Example from the Comments
You asked about a slightly different layout in the comments. If you want Love and your name on the same line:
#!/usr/bin/ruby

EVENT = "30th birthday"
MY_BEST_FRIEND = "Larry"
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = "Sarah"
puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!", "Love, #{YOUR_BEST_FRIEND}"

If you want them on separate lines, you just pass Love, and your name as separate arguments to Kernel#puts and remove the interpolation on the last item. For example:
#!/usr/bin/ruby

EVENT = "30th birthday"
MY_BEST_FRIEND = "Larry"
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = "Sarah"
puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!", "Love,", YOUR_BEST_FRIEND

Again, if it's a round cake, you might need to wrap that last line. In that case, this will do the same thing but will be more likely to fit horizontally:
#!/usr/bin/ruby

EVENT = "30th birthday"
MY_BEST_FRIEND = "Larry"
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = "Sarah"
puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!",
  "Love,", YOUR_BEST_FRIEND

In the final example, you can also use "    #{YOUR_BEST_FRIEND}" as the last argument to #puts if you want to indent your name rather than having it left-justified. It's all a matter of taste, if you'll pardon the cake pun!
It's the Thought That Counts
There's no real right answer. There are certainly other ways to do this, too. Pick the one that you like, run the code in IRB if you want to make sure it does what you want, and then go with the one you think will fit the cake, your budget, and your sense of fun. I suspect Larry will enjoy the gesture no matter which option you choose.

Todd, this is amazing and super helpful. Admittedly, I understand about 50% of this as I don’t speak your language (programming). I am in marketing.
However, I think I get the overall message. How would the below work? #!/usr/bin/ruby
EVENT = "30th birthday"
MY_BEST_FRIEND = "Larry"
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = “Sarah”
msg = "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!"
“Love,”
EM_DASH #{YOUR_BEST_FRIEND}

(I cannot even figure out how to add each line item here on different lines, so hopefully this makes sense.) Again, appreciate your input!

You can replace the semicolons in the following with newlines (a carriage return) instead since comments on this site don't allow for multi-line formatting. The source code you want is: EVENT = "30th birthday"; MY_BEST_FRIEND = "Larry"; YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = "Sarah"; puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!", "Love, #{YOUR_BEST_FRIEND}". I'll add it to the answer.

Awesome. Just added a photo with the edits. Thoughts? Makes sense or anything glaringly off?

@programmersgirlfriend I added a couple of variations of the code you wanted as posted in the comments. In the example, even if it looks weird, you need to have the two commas after Love if you're splitting the lines: one inside the quotes and one outside. That's why I offered the option of having Love, Sarah on a single line. It looks less weird in the code to not split those lines, but that's just my personal opinion. It's your gift and Larry's birthday!

A very ruby-like thing is how one creates Structs with it, e.g.
#!/sja/bin/env ruby
Birthday = Struct.new("Birthday", :name, :age) do
  def greet
    puts "Happy #{age}. birthday #{name}"
  end
end

my_best_friend = Birthday.new("Larry", 30)
my_best_friend.greet;
=> Happy 30. birthday Larry

It's running code if you change sja to usr.

Happy "31th" birthday eh?

The biggest challenge with this is the cake size and the decorator's skill. There's not much to add to what Todd A Jacobs has already said above except:
The Shebang:
The shebang #!/usr/bin/ruby is optional. If this file is set to be executable (for Macs and Linux this would be via the chmod a+x command and in Windows I think it's via the user interface) this first line tells the operating system (ie: Windows, Mac OS, Linux, etc) where to find the interpreter to run the code in the rest of the file. With the shebang, you can run the program from the terminal/command line by typing the path to the file. Without it you'd have to write the path to the Ruby interpreter followed by the file name. As an example, if you call the file cake_msg.rb with the shebang you can run it by typing ./cake_msg.rb at the command line (presuming you're in the folder where the file exists indicated by ./). You can thus omit it and instead type ruby ./cake_msg.rb.
Horizontal Space:
If your cake is rectangular I'm worried the last line will be too long. As Todd mentioned, you can break up the line. An alternative to puts is print and even p. I think using more puts makes for a nicer message. For the last line I use .to_s to convert the value to a string. I'd even throw in \n\n to add an extra line before the salutation:
EVENT = '30th birthday'
MY_BEST_FRIEND = 'Larry'
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = 'Sarah'
puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!\n\n"
puts 'Love,'
puts YOUR_BEST_FRIEND.to_s

Sheet Cake:
My above example could work on a round cake. With a rectangular cake we should make the most of the space and really Rubyize it. Variables in UPPER_CASE stylistically indicate constants (ie: the data in them should never change). For Ruby, these strings should be frozen using .freeze which makes the syntax even more obviously Ruby.
EVENT = '30th birthday'.freeze
MY_BEST_FRIEND = 'Larry'.freeze
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = 'Sarah'.freeze
puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!\n\n"
puts 'Love,'
puts YOUR_BEST_FRIEND.to_s

This can be done by adding a special line (requires at least ruby v2.3). So here's my most vertically verbose option for you:
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

EVENT = '30th birthday'
MY_BEST_FRIEND = 'Larry'
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = 'Sarah'
puts "Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!\n\n"
puts 'Love,'
puts YOUR_BEST_FRIEND.to_s

Make it Loopy:
My final and longest suggestion adds an array [] that is looped through to make the output. This version reduces the duplicate puts code. The interpreter loops through each part of the array placing the contents into txt (which is a variable because the content changes and is thus lower_case).
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

EVENT = '30th birthday'
MY_BEST_FRIEND = 'Larry'
YOUR_BEST_FRIEND = 'Sarah'

["Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!",
 '', 'Love,',
 YOUR_BEST_FRIEND.to_s].each do |txt|
   puts txt
end


Personally, I'd avoid the last version since puts ["Happy #{EVENT}, #{MY_BEST_FRIEND}!", '', 'Love,', YOUR_BEST_FRIEND.to_s] has the same result, wouldn't want a "code smelly" cake. Using a HEREDOC could be a nice addition though

@engineersmnky a code smelly cake, best SO quote ever.
